# ¿Alguien podría explicarme ciclos anidados?

Tags: javascript

Es que estoy aprendiendo ciclos for en ***Javascript*** pero me vino un ciclo for anidado a otro y no entiendo perfectamente como funciona esto. Según lo que vi en un resultado es que se multiplica uno por otro (o algo parecido) pero la verdad es que no entiendo de que manera se multiplica o de que manera funciona este código.

¿Si no formule bien mi pregunta díganmelo?, por favor.

Gracias de antemano.

```
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es algo así:

```
 var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
 // el primer **for** es el tamaño total del arreglo (array),
 // es decir la cantidad de elementos que tiene el array en este caso es 3,
 // array [ [elemento1], [elemento2], [elemento3] ]
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   // tamaño total de uno de los array ejemplo
   // cuando dice arr[i] = arr[[elemento1, elemento2]],
   // con esto tenemos que el tamaño seria 2
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { 
      // cuando i= 0 y j = 0  **i** sería el primer array y
      // **j** seria a la primera posición del primer array
      // es decir arr[0][0] = 1
      // es decir arr[0][1] = 2
      // acá saldría del primer ciclo y **i** es igual a 1 y
      // **j** se reinicia y queda en 0 la segunda pasada sería así
       // arr[1][0] = 3
       // arr[1][1] = 4
       // esto sucedería hasta que termine de recorrer los **for**
       console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Recuerda que los arreglos en JavaScript se empiezan a recorrer desde el índice cero (0), siendo esta la primera posición.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]; //Este es un arreglo con otros arreglos internos
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { //Aquí estas iterando la variable arr
for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { //Aquí estas iterando los arreglos de la variable arr que propiamente tambien es un arreglo
console.log(arr[i][j]); //Imprimes en la consola.
}
}
```

---

***...Edición por continuidad***

`arr.length // Como variable arr es un arreglo, todos los arreglos contienen en su naturalidad esta propiedad lenth; y esta propiedad cuenta el total de datos que almacena dicho arreglo`

Explicamos;

Entonces, cuando el código indica: `var i=0; i<arr.length; i++` significa; iniciamos una variable llamda `i` en su valor `0`, el ciclo continuará solo siempre y cuando `i` sea menor que `arr.length` (el total de los valores que contiene arr; 3 para este ejemplo) y por ultimo incrementamos el valor de `i` en 1 unidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias! pero hay una cosa que aun no me queda muy clara, en la parte donde dice "arr.length" ¿qué quiere decir? ¿se supone que va a parar cuando que o que? me vendría de mucha ayuda si me explicaras eso

Comment: Listo ya edite la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente lo que haces con ese código es recorrer un arreglo multidimensional, es decir una matriz

```
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]; 
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { 
    console.log(arr[i][j]); //Imprimes en la consola.
  }
}
```

al declarar var arr tienes una matriz 3x2

```
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]
```

Con el primer ciclo for recorres las filas por lo que `arr.length` seria = 3, con el segundo ciclo for recorres las columnas por lo que `arr[i].length` seria igual a 2.

Una vez que tienes i y j puedes acceder a las posiciones del array. 
Puedes comprobar esto haciendo un

```
console.log(arr[0][0]);
```

Ya que esos valores son los que se reemplazan por i y j.

Comment: Cuidado. No todos los arreglos multidimensionales son matrices. Por ejemplo considera `var arr2 = [ [1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]];`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!